# Does GWT support Jquery?

Tags: jquery, gwt

I want to add a simple jquery function to Gwt using jsni. But am not getiing the functionality. Does Gwt support Jquery or I had to go for GWTQuery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT is Java, which is cross compiled to JavaScript. This means that all your application development is done in Java. jQuery is a JavaScript library and calling JavaScript methods with GWT isn't that easy (Of course you can [JSNI](http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) but still...)

That's why they made GwtQuery!

> GwtQuery is easy to learn for those using jQuery as they share the same api, additionally jQuery adds nice features like type-safe css, compile time optimizations, etc.
>   ([Source](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/))

I'm using GwtQuery in my project and must say it's really easy to use and you can make all nice effects from jQuery with it.

Google mentioned GwtQuery explicitly at their I/O conference (check it out [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9A4FqholOY)).

**All in all , if you are using Gwt you can use GwtQuery to access all functions from jQuery**

Answer (score 1):

If you use GWT, then GwtQuery is better then jQuery because:

1. It is smaller: GWT compiler just compiles code that is used, so if you use a function or two from GwtQuery it will produce code much smaller then whole jQuery library.
2. It's type safe and as a GWT library supported by your IDE.
3. It's [faster](http://gwtquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/gwtquery.samples.GwtQueryBench/GwtQueryBench.html)!
4. No separate download - cuts down on page startup time.